# User login does not work

Tags: login, user

My user login doesn't work. If I create an account, that works, but if I log off and try to log in again, no dice. I'm running this locally on the mac localhost web server. Does this have something to do with my key? If so, where do I put that?

v 2.0.13

Thanks.

Comment: please specify your magento version

Comment: What is happening when you send the login form? Are seeing any message, do you get 404 page, do you see login page again without any information?

Comment: Nothing happens. It just returns to the login page.

Comment: OK, turns out this is a problem with Chrome. Just tried it in IE and it works. any ideas why?